# CoreLocation crashes on device but not on simulator

Tags: iphone, core-location

Keep getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS. Ran NSZombieEnabled and came up with nothing.

In simulator console:

```
 2010-09-11 23:39:56.876 [19072:207] 1.309789, lat, 103.772196, lon
```

In device console:

```
EXC_BAD_ACCESS
```

The line of code:

```
 NSLog(@"%f, lat, %f, lon",latitudeString,longitudeString);
```

What CLManager is doing:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
 NSLog(@"Entering mlocationmanager did updatetolocation");
    latitudeString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", newLocation.coordinate.latitude];

    longitudeString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", newLocation.coordinate.longitude];

  NSLog(@"lat %@ long %@", latitudeString, longitudeString);
 NSLog(@"%@",newLocation.description);
 if (latitudeString.length >0 && longitudeString.length > 0){
  NSLog(@"Yes both are more than 0");
  locationIsReady = YES;

 }
 [self.tableView reloadData]; 
}
```

What is happening here? Both variables are in my header file and CLLocationManagerDelegate is conformed to. Been working on this for a few hours, but no luck. Hope you guys can help.

```
NSString *latitudeString;
 NSString *longitudeString;
```

Answer (score 2):

You really do not need to convert `newLocation.coordinate.longitude` to an `NSString` to print it. Simply use `%f` in the format string to print them.

Also, when you write:

```
if (latitudeString.length >0 && longitudeString.length > 0)
```

You are comparing the **length** of the strings, which will **always** be greater than zero. BEcause if the longitude or latitude is zero, the converted string will be `@"0.0"` which has a length of `3`. I suspect what you really want here is:

```
if (newLocation.coordinate.latitude != 0.0
    && newLocation.coordinate.longitude != 0.0)
```

Comment: (0,0) is a perfectly valid coordinate though; it just happens to be in the ocean somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

The line of code should indeed be your culprit:

```
NSLog(@"%f, lat, %f, lon",latitudeString,longitudeString);
```

The correct `NSLog` format argument for Objective-C objects is `%@`. `%f` is for floating-point numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Finally fixed it after a long while.

Took me some time to realize that NSXMLParser was actually overriding some of my variables (I have no idea why). So in the end, I called CLLocationManager after my XML had parsed. Problem solved.

Comment: You have no idea why so you moved some code around and now it just happens to work. I think you better find the real cause.

Comment: Your code is definitely doing something wrong; you've probably just moved the crash somewhere else.